# Cancelled hung GParted operation; didn't 'Force Cancel'; How do I get out without losing data?

Tags: partition, hard-disk, gparted, partition-table

In GParted, I was moving a partition over 200mb to the left. However, when it got to 76.13gb of about 330gb done, it stopped (it was stuck at 76.13gb all night).

So, I hit cancel (without properly thinking through what this actually meant for the now-half-copied partition). When I hit `cancel`, GParted changed the cancel button to Force Cancel`. If you click this, it warns about data loss.

Is it possible to either force it to resume, or to fix it, or to cancel safely?

My thought was just to force cancel, then use GParted's undo function. However, I'm not sure if the undo process will work with a half-completed previous operation.

Since this drive is ntfs-formatted and contains only media, it shouldn't cause any problems with booting/OS, which means that I'll still be able to work on the drive even if I screw up the partitioning.

Based on [this thread on LQ](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/by-cancelling-a-gparted-partitioning-operation-i%27ve-lost-my-os-635811/), I think it should be possible to restore from the old Partition table -- if I can find it.

Comment: Anything in `dmesg`? `smartctl -a /dev/sdx` for the drive in question? Even if the drive is not broke you should probably `ddrescue` the current state [entire disk] to another drive first.

Comment: I would just restore the data from the backup that you made before fiddling with the partition table.

Comment: @Anthon If I was smart, I would have done that. (I didn't because I'm an idiot)

Comment: The only other drive I have has a bunch of junk on it that needs to be cleared out before I can do anything. I'll do that and back up current state when I get home from school!

Comment: @frostschutz can I do that with GParted still running?

Comment: @evamvid if gparted is stuck and not actually writing to disk - yes. Also it's not possible to fix a botched overlapping move just by changing the partition table. You have to finish the move or undo the move.

Comment: @frostschutz dmesg output. I deleted a whole bunch of stuff at the beginning of it that had to do with my keyboard (logitech g15/g15daemon) . I think the important stuff is around line 606. This link also has the smartctl output. https://gist.github.com/evamvid/4fb77a71514a2e1171a9

Comment: @frostschutz will ddrescue wipe the drive used for backup? What format does it back up in?